# f# Assignment of function's return value to an object, using microsoft odbc

Tags: vb.net, f#

in VB I have this code,

```
Dim dataset As System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

which creates an object with the results of cmd.Execute Reader of type OdbcDataReader and assigns it to dataset. cmd is a System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand object.

In f# I've tried

```ml
let  dataset = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader
    dataset <- cmd.ExecuteReader
```

as well as a mutable version of dataset,  I've also tried

```ml
let dataset = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

The first one errors on the second instance of dataset saying "Incomplete structured construct at or before this point in the expression" adding a semicolon doesnt help.

The  second one errors  on the let; saying the expression is not complete.  How do I create an object with the result of System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader?

edit:

More code

```ml
let dataConnection = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection()
dataConnection.ConnectionString <- "*******"
let mystring = "SQL query"

let cmd = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand(mystring, dataConnection)
let odbcConnectFunction = 

    try
        dataConnection.Open()
        System.Console.WriteLine "connected"
        //let  dataset = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader
        let dataset = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    finally
    dataConnection.Close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `cmd` is typed as an `OdbcCommand` directly, you should be able to just call it, as [`OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhcdfhz9.aspx) already returns the appropriate type, and the type inference will "just work":

```ml
let dataset = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

If `cmd` is typed as a `DbCommand`, however, you'd need some extra code here.

In the VB code, you're creating a variable with the type you want (`OdbcDataReader`), and letting the language implicity change the type from a `DbDataReader` to an `OdbcDataReader`.  F# is more particular about types, and won't implicitly change the types for you.

You need to do the cast explicitly in F#:

```ml
let dataset = cmd.ExecuteReader() :?> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader
```

Comment: Why? `OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader` returns an OdbcDataReader: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhcdfhz9.aspx he shouldn't have to cast it.

Comment: @vcsjones I *suspect* that his command is typed as a `DbCommand`, so he's calling: `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc093a69(v=vs.110).aspx`, in which case the return value will be `DbDataReader`

Comment: I think I have the types correct. cmd is an object of System.Data.Odbc.Command

Comment: @Edeast is is `System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand`?  (Note that the type name isn't just `Command` there)

Comment: I've just tried, "let dataset = cmd.ExecuteReader()"  the error, is" block following this let is unfinished, expects an expression"

Comment: @Edeast Can you edit to show more of your code - I suspect there's something else going on... that should work fine.

Comment: It is System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand, I misstyped in my comment.

Comment: @Edeast Code is missing some critical parts - want to discuss in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f ?

Comment: I'll chat when I'm able. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Edeast If you do something with dataset after that line, it should work